# The "elevator pitch" for this site is slightly ungrammatical

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The "elevator pitch" (not sure what the exact name is) for this site , which you can see at the top of the [tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour), is as follows:

> Bicycles is a question and answer site for people who build and repair bicycles, train bicycling, or commute on bicycles.

I think that "train bicycling" is ungrammatical, and should be replaced with something else - perhaps "train at bicycling" (though that sounds sort of stilted).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's grammatical or not... "bicycling" in that form looks like a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) (noun-equivalent), which would require the transitive form of "train", but we're not training the bicycling, so that's not right. Can it be an adverbial present participle in this context? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing#Distinction_between_gerunds_and_present_participles

Comment: Either way, I think you're right that there's room for improvement, since it does sound odd and/or unclear to some native English speakers...  I don't think "train at bicycling" is an improvement, though.

Comment: Maybe we should ask on http://english.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: How about "build, repair, and ride bicycles"?

Comment: @jimirings That certainly seems a good deal punchier.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know people read the elevator pitches. But it does sound odd.

Comment: And now it's different. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, let's change from this:

> **Bicycles** is a question and answer site for people who build and repair bicycles, train bicycling, or commute on bicycles. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about bicycles and bicycling.

To this:

> **Bicycles** is a question and answer site for people who build, repair, or ride bicycles. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about bicycles and bicycling.

Or, even better, move the most important thing first:

> **Bicycles** is a question and answer site for people who ride, repair, or build bicycles. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about bicycles and bicycling.

Comment: That last version is now live

Answer (score 0):

'Train cyclists' seems as though it would be a very good fit here?
Possibly also 'train cycling' would be appropriate

Comment: I don't like either of those suggestions. "Train cyclists" sounds like coaching, which is on-topic but doesn't include people who are riding a bike in order to improve their bicycling performance. "Train cycling" just changes "bicycling" to the less clear "cycling" and doesn't fix the grammar at all.

Comment: I really like your answer but would suggest 'build, repair or ride' (I can't comment on others posts yet :( )

Comment: And @freiheit... Sorry, me being pedantic, you should remove the comma before or

Comment: @Stamfordone Comma or not depends on the writing style you use for your english, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_comma I for myself like it ;-) and don't mind having it there.

Comment: Fair enough, you learn something new every day!

Comment: @Stamfordone That comma was a deliberate choice. I default to the Oxford/serial comma unless it might increase ambiguity.

Comment: That works for me, never heard of it before so always went with what I thought I knew